# pass value/variable from fancybox iframe to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox-2

I'am trying to pass a variable/ value from the fancybox iframe to the parent window without success.

Fancybox is launched from a link with

```
   class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"
```

My code in the fancybox.iframe is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.insert_single').click(function(){
    var test =  $('.members_body').find('{row.U_USERNAME}');
    setTimeout(function(){ parent.$.fancybox.close();},300);return true;

   });
});
```

Where '{row.U_USERNAME}' is the username to find in the iframe.

Then, in the parent there's the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.fancybox').fancybox(

  {
openEffect:'fade',
openSpeed:500,


    afterClose: function(){
    alert($(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find(test)); 
    $('#form input[name=username]').val()(test);return false;
    }
}                   

  );
 });
```

But when the fancybox is closed, there's no alert showing up with the variable "test", nor the variable is showing up as a value or as a text in the input field of the form.

I've read and tried various solutions found here on stackoverflow without success.

Thanks in advance for helping

**EDIT**

Here's an [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NXY7Y/9/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the fancybox is closed the iframe is removed from the document. So you must use `beforeClose` event instead of `afterClose`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
        openEffect:'fade',
        openSpeed:500,
        beforeClose: function() {
            // working
            var $iframe = $('.fancybox-iframe');
            alert($('input', $iframe.contents()).val());
        },
        afterClose: function() {
            // not working
            var $iframe = $('.fancybox-iframe');
            alert($('input', $iframe.contents()).val());
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NXY7Y/1/

**EDIT:**

I edited your jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/NXY7Y/9/). Update is in this link
http://jsfiddle.net/NXY7Y/13/

Main page javscript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
        openEffect:'fade',
        openSpeed:500//,
        //beforeClose: function() {
        //    // working
        //    var $iframe = $('.fancybox-iframe');
        //    alert($('input', $iframe.contents()).val());
        //},
        //afterClose: function() {
        //    // not working
        //    var $iframe = $('.fancybox-iframe');
        //    alert($('input', $iframe.contents()).val());
        //}
    });
});

function setSelectedUser(userText) {
    $('#username').val(userText);
}
```

No need to use `afterClose` or `beforeClose` events. Just access the parent function `setSelectedUser` from the iframe on link click event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.insert_single').click(function() {
        parent.setSelectedUser($(this).text());
        parent.$.fancybox.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: `('{row.U_USERNAME}')` isn't a input field in the iframe. When a link is clicked next to the username in the iframe i get this username (`$('.insert_single').click(function()`). Then i want to get this username as a value into a text field in the parent window.

Comment: I just put an example of how to access any element inside a iframe and when/where you have to do it (`beforeClose`). replace the selector 'input' with your selector...

Comment: As alert message i get `object Object`. My code in the `beforeClose` function is: ` var $iframe = $('.fancybox-iframe');alert($('.insert_single', $iframe.contents()));` This is problem 1. The second problem is: how to get the username in the text field. Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NXY7Y/4/)

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add the class to the links. Updated fiddle is [http://jsfiddle.net/NXY7Y/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/NXY7Y/9/)

Comment: GREAT! Thank you very much arvic.rivera

Comment: +1 - I posted an alternative solution without setting any jQuery inside the child page.

Answer (score 3):

Some clarifications :

- You should use `.find()` to find elements by selector (you are trying to find a variable `.find(test)`, which is not a valid format).
- You should use `.val()` to get the contents of an `input` field or `.val(new_value)` to set the contents of an `input` field
- You should use `.html()` or `.text()` to get the contents of any element other than `input`,

example: having this html code

```
<p class="test">hola</p>
```

... and this jQuery code

```
var temp = $(".test").html();
```

... `temp` will return `hola`.

On the other hand, if you have control over the iframed page and it's under the same domain than the parent page, then you may not need to set any jQuery in the child page.

so, having this html in the child (iframed) page for instance

```
<div class="members_body">
    <p>GOOGLE</p>
    <p>JSFIDDLE</p>
    <p>STACKOVERFLOW</p>
</div>
```

You could set this jQuery in your parent page to get the contents of any clicked element in your child page :

```
var _tmpvar; // the var to use through the callbacks
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        afterShow: function () {
            var $iframe = $('.fancybox-iframe');
            $iframe.contents().find(".members_body p").each(function (i) {
                $(this).on("click", function () {
                    _tmpvar = $('.members_body p:eq(' + i + ')', $iframe.contents()).html();
                    $.fancybox.close();
                }); // on click
            }); // each
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            $('#form input[name=username]').val(_tmpvar);
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

Notice that we declared the var `_tmpvar` globally so we can use it within different callbacks.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u7F9C/show/)**

Comment: Nice one. I like the effect of setting the input text on `afterClose`. +1