# Update a drop down list after closing fancybox iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox, parent

I got an `iFrame` that opens in `fancybox` which opens a form where a user can enter details of a new customer.

I however was wondering if/how it is possible to update the parent page but not the whole page, just the customer drop down so the new customer added in the `iFrame` is displayed in the list.

This is the code I got at the moment which updates the whole page on close

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#NewCustomer").fancybox({
            type: "iframe",
            href: "EditCustomer.aspx",
              'onClosed': function() {
                parent.location.reload(true);
        });

    });
```

This is my customer dropdown

```
<td align="right">Customer:</td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dllCustomer" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox">    </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" id="NewCustomer" name="NewCustomer" value="Create New Customer" />                           
   </td>
```

If this does not make sense please ask, I think I made it as clear as I can

Comment: Does `parent.$('#elementid').selectedIndex=3` work? Of course change the values to what works on your form.

Comment: Nope does not appear to work

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/23686635/1055987 this code retrieves a value from the iframed page and updates a field on the parent page. Notice that is for fancybox 2.x. If you are using fancybox v1.3.4 then use `onComplete` and `onClosed` instead and use the proper fancybox selectors